# Handle different click events on one element

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, addeventlistener

I am trying to implement a solution which allows to attach 3 different handlers to an element, but none should trigger the others.

Using https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html as reference

```
<div @click.ctrl="methodA" @click="methodB" @contextmenu.ctrl="methodC"></div>
```

I've tried using .stop modifier randomly on each but I am unable to prevent methodA to also trigger methodB when I click. What would be the right way/modifiers to use or would the order I attach the handlers matter?

#### Edit

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVrGKo

Comment: This question could be improved by adding a codepen or fiddle to be able to reproduce the error and to make the task of helping you easier.

Comment: Added codepen example as requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I created my own pen to test this and I could see the same thing you described in your questions happening in there as well, however with the pen you created I couldn't see that happening.

Anyhow, it does make sense that @click is triggered when @click.ctrl is triggered. But you can prevent that from happening by using the [.exact modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#exact-Modifier) so the events get triggered only when the exact combination is used. Like this:

```
<div 
  @click.ctrl="methodA" 
  @click.exact="methodB"
  @contextmenu.ctrl="methodC"
></div>
```

Use [this pen](https://codepen.io/jaireina/pen/OGxMLg) as an example

Let me know if that works.

Comment: sad... I should have read the whole event page. I never saw the exact modifier before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: NP! Happens to me all the time.